# self-join eager loading recursively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a self-joined model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Comment', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
     has_many :children, :class_name => 'Comment', :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

Later I wish to first make 1 sql call to grab all relevant comments, and then recursively render them.

How do I recursively eager load?

```
comments = Comment.where(:post_id => @post_id).includes(:comments=> [:comments => [:comments .... #How do I get this to recursively eager load?

def show_comments(comment)
   render comment
   comment.children.each do |child|
       show_comments(child)
   end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `show_comments(child)`?

Comment: Oh yeah, there's probably typos in the code, it's just meant to present a general idea of what i want.

Comment: simply put : you can't. I would advise using [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) or [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) that are both different implementations addressing this problem (deeply nested structures on a single table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a method that retrieves the deep nesting of IDs, load those, and rails will use it like a cache.